# Negative exponents and positive numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is it that when we raise a positive number to a negative power, we don't get a negative number?

Comment: Because exponentiation is not multiplication.

Comment: Ask yourself 2 questions: (1) what happens to the exponent when we multiply by the base (e.g. $2^5 \times 2$)  (2) What happens to the exponent when you divide by the base (e.g. $\frac{2^5}{2}$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define negative exponents, you define them in a way that the power laws still hold. In particular,
$$a^{-n}a^n = a^{-n+n} = a^0 = 1$$
From this you immediately see that $a^{-1}$ is positive, since $a^n$ and $1$ are both positive, but the product of a negative and a positive number is negative.

Indeed, the formula above just says that
$$a^{-n} = \frac{1}{a^n}$$

Answer (score 13):

Because negative exponents are defined such that $a^{-b} = \dfrac{1}{a^b}$. Its just a convention.

Think about it this way: because of the exponent law $x^{a} x^{b} = x^{a+b}$, we must have $a^b a^{-b} = a^{b+(-b)} = a^0 = 1$. Therefore, because $a^b a^{-b} = 1$, we have $a^{-b} = \dfrac{1}{a^b}$.

Comment: I don't think convention is the right word. Rather, it's a **consequence** of the definition of exponentiation.

Comment: @user3002473: _consequence_ is too strong; nothing would actually stop you from defining the negative powers differently. The common definition just makes a lot of sense, since it retains the power laws.

Answer (score 3):

A negative exponent is just another way of writing $x^y$ where $x,y > 0$ as $\dfrac{1}{x^y}$.

Since a positive number raised to a positive exponent is positive and the reciprocal of a positive number is positive. We have that $x^{-y}$ is positive.

Using the familiar power laws we have that $$a^{b}a^{-b} = a^{b - b} = a^0 = 1 \implies a^{-b} = \frac{1}{a^{b}}$$

So we have shown why we can write $x^{-y}$ as $\dfrac{1}{x^y}$.

Comment: You don't explain why a negative exponent raises the reciprocal of the base x to the yth power. Saying that a negative exponent is just another way of writing something is relying on convention and not explaining anything. You may have answered my question, but I was looking more for an explanation of how the power laws work.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Yes. Now I can see why it is that we can rewrite it, and your reasoning makes more sense.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also approach it graphically. If you look at the graph of $e^x$ when $x > 0$, this function is always positive. Likewise when $x < 0$, it is also positive. Hence, by definition, it will always be positive whether you raise it to a positive power or otherwise.

Comment: Right, but integer powers are a rather more fundamental (algebraic) concept than the exponential function (which requires calculus), so it's a bit weird to deduce the former from the latter..

Comment: You're right, it was the first example that came to mind.

Comment: This didn't really help. Looking at a graph doesn't explain why the power laws hold. Of course, I could see that when x is negative then the graph of f(x) is still positive, but my question is why that is?